# Have to click element twice for Jquery event to work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have an ajax function that I have to click twice to work. I would like it to just work with one click. It was working before I added a click event that checks the text of what I'm clicking and uses it as part of the URL. My problem likely resides there. I need a fresh perspective on what might be wrong.

Jquery:

```
function ajaxShow(){    
        $('#formats a').click(function(e) {
          var txt = $(e.target).text();
          console.log(txt);

    $.ajax({
        url : "./enablereports/" + txt + ".html",
        data: "html",
        contentType:"application/x-javascript; charset:ISO-8859-1",
            beforeSend: function(jqXHR) {
            jqXHR.overrideMimeType('text/html;charset=iso-8859-1');
            },
        success : function (data) {
            $("#rightDiv").html(data);
        }
    });
            });

}
```

HTML:

```
   <body>
    <div id="wrapper">
        <div id="enablestuff" class="yellowblock">
            <h3 id="title" class="header">Enable Formats</h3>
        </div>
        <div id="formats" class="lightorangeblock">
            <a href="" onclick="ajaxShow();event.preventDefault()">ADDSTAMP</a><br>
            <a href="" onclick="ajaxShow();event.preventDefault()">SCLGLDNB</a><br>
            <a href="" onclick="ajaxShow();event.preventDefault()">SCLGLVNB</a><br>

        </div>

    </div>      

    <div id="rightWrap">
       <div id="rightDiv">
       </div>
    </div>

   </body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that each of the anchor elements has an inline event handler that points to `ajaxShow`, which then sets up the actual event handler for future clicks.

Instead, eliminate the inline handlers and just set up the actual handler without the `ajaxShow` wrapper.

I would also suggest that you don't use `<a>` elements since you aren't actually navigating anywhere, so the use of the element is semantically incorrect and will cause problems for people who rely on assistive technologies to use the web. Instead, since you want line breaks in between each "link", use `<div>` elements and just style them to look like links.

Lastly, you've used the `name` attribute on one of your last `div` elements, but `name` is only valid on form fields. You could give it an `id` if needed.

```js
$('#formats div').click(function(e) {
   var txt = $(e.target).text();
   console.log(txt);

   $.ajax({
    url : "./enablereports/" + txt + ".html",
    data: "html",
    contentType:"application/x-javascript; charset:ISO-8859-1",
     beforeSend: function(jqXHR) {
       jqXHR.overrideMimeType('text/html;charset=iso-8859-1');
     },
     success : function (data) {
      $("#rightDiv").html(data);
     }
    }); 
});
```

```css
#formats div { text-decoration:underline; color:blue; cursor:pointer; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="wrapper">
 <div id="enablestuff" class="yellowblock">
  <h3 id="title" class="header">Enable Formats</h3>
 </div>
 <div id="formats" class="lightorangeblock">
  <div>ADDSTAMP</div>
  <div>SCLGLDNB</div>
  <div>SCLGLVNB</div> 
 </div>
</div>  
<div id="rightWrap">
  <div id="rightDiv"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: @shadoe2020 What does "did not work" mean? Do you get an error in your Console? As you can see, it works here, so there must be an error somewhere else in your code.

Comment: I means I had the same result and had to click twice. You are probably right. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

It's cause you're binding the jQuery handler inside of your `onclick` function - just remove the entire `onclick` attribute and bind your handler outside the function.

```
$('#formats a').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var txt = $(e.target).text();
    console.log(txt);

    $.ajax({
        url : "./enablereports/" + txt + ".html",
        data: "html",
        contentType:"application/x-javascript; charset:ISO-8859-1",
            beforeSend: function(jqXHR) {
            jqXHR.overrideMimeType('text/html;charset=iso-8859-1');
            },
        success : function (data) {
            $("#rightDiv").html(data);
        }
    });
});
```

And the HTML

```
<div id="formats" class="lightorangeblock">
    <a href="">ADDSTAMP</a><br>
    <a href="">SCLGLDNB</a><br>
    <a href="">SCLGLVNB</a><br> 
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for the recommendation. This did not work for me though.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get this working by adding ajaxShow(); into a $(document).ready(function ().

Dirty, but it works.